# How to get list of full url categories and products in it, via PHP from database?

Tags: php, opencart

I want to get list of full url products in Opencart 3.0.3.2 via Php from database:

Example:

```py
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_27&product_id=39
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=25_28&product_id=40
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=25&product_id=41
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=24_28&product_id=42
...
```

and so on.

Of course it would be so good if u tell me how to get it and save in .xlsx format. Get all products in order, even without numerical order. Just links!

In database I have: **'products_in_category'** table where I have two columns:

```py
Product_id  Category_id
28           20
28           24
29           20
29           24
30           25
30           24
32           26

.... and so on
```

As you see the same products are repeat because of this product linked on 'Parent category' and 'subcategory'

But I need full path to products without repetitions!

Expecting results -> File .xlsx(Excel) *would be great!, or just .txt file:

```py
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_27&product_id=39
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=25_28&product_id=40
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=25&product_id=41
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=24_28&product_id=42
...
```

**Expecting result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sql statement

```
SELECT CONCAT("http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=", GROUP_CONCAT(category_id SEPARATOR '_'), "&product_id=", product_id) AS 'Product_links' FROM `oc_product_to_category` GROUP BY product_id
```